# NullPointerException error and Stack Overflow error on assigning values to JTextFields

Tags: java, swing

This is the current version of the problem I have tried but there was no solution to the problem, please let me know how I can initialize JtextFields in this situation

```
public class Teacher_Profile extends JFrame {

private JTextField textField_5;
private JTextField textField_6;
private JTextField textField_7;
private JTextField textField_8;

private JTextArea textArea;

private JComboBox comboBox;
private JComboBox comboBox_1;

private LoginDAO a;
private Teacher_Profile g = new Teacher_Profile(this);
private Teacher hi = new Teacher();

    public Teacher_Profile() {
    super();
}

public Teacher_Profile(Teacher_Profile aq) {
    super();
    this.g = aq;
}

public Teacher_Profile(Teacher v) {

    a = new LoginDAO();
    textField_5 = new JTextField();
    textField_6 = new JTextField();
    textField_7 = new JTextField();
textField_8 = new JTextField();

    JButton btnClear = new JButton("Get");
    btnClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Get"))
            {
                Marks_Details ss = a.fetchMarksData(comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().toString(),textField_7.getText());

                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Type: " + ss.getType() + "\nMax_Marks: " + Integer.toString(ss.getMax_Marks()) + "\nWeightage: " + Float.toString(ss.getWeightage()) + "\n Course_Code: " + ss.getCourse_Code());

                g.textField_5.setText(ss.getType().toString());
                g.textField_6.setText(Integer.toString(ss.getMax_Marks()));
                g.textField_7.setText(Float.toString(ss.getWeightage()));
                g.comboBox.setSelectedItem(ss.getCourse_Code());
            }
        }
    });
    btnClear.setBounds(236, 269, 89, 23);
    panel_1.add(btnClear);
```

This is what I have tried but getting stack overflowerror

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at private Teacher_Profile g = new Teacher_Profile(this);
```

Comment: Please show where you declare and initialize your text fields.

Comment: This seems null - `g.textField_5`. Can you print it and let us know?

Comment: Please ignore the statement g = this.g; in this code

Comment: Where do you initialize your textfields?

Comment: `g` is still uninitialized.

Comment: Before we continue: please post your correct and used code. It is counterproductive if you update your question every five minutes.

Comment: I have also tried using following statement

private static Teacher_Profile g = new Teacher_Profile();

public Teacher_Profile() {
  super();
  g = this;
 }

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the `Teacher_Profile g` variable?

Comment: Teacher_Profile g is the class (current Interface) where all of these JtextFields are defined...
Based on the ID entered by user I am trying to get data assign to textfields...

Comment: You explained `Teacher_Profile`, but not `g`. Why do you store a `Teacher_Profile` inside of a `Teacher_Profile`? What would you loose if you just remove it?

Comment: My bad, just removed Teacher_Profile g and it worked. Thanks